# Control applications without touching screen for disabled people

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there anyway to pick a button of one app without touching the screen? I'm developing an application for disabled people and I need to control other applications without touching the screen. I can do somethings with Intent class, but is not always the solution. For example you can't send a whatsapp without touching screen with intent (you can put text in the box with intent, or view a conversation with an specific contact, but you can't send a whatsapp, you need to pick physically the specific button), so I was wondering if there is a method to pick the buttons displayed in the screen without touching it from my app, which is running in background.

Sorry, im new in the post. Now im triying to control whatsapp from my app with this code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();    
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");    
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of the message");    
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");    
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {    
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent, REQUEST_SEND_WHATSAPP);   
}
```

This code let me initialize whatsapp and set text in the box, but i have to choose the contact, and press manually the send button to send the message. I want to do it without touching anything, is it possible?
Thank you very much! And sorry about my english.

Comment: If you post some code from your researches, it will help answerer

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the [Accessibility framework.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/package-summary.html)

It requires additional permissions and the user will need to explicitly enable Accessibility for your application.

Figuring out how to find the correct UI widget can be daunting, but play with it and see if you can figure it out, or look at some tutorials.